# Extract values from a column value containing a list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column containing values that also contains a list of values. E.g,

```
actor = ["[Emil Eifrem,Hugo Weaving,Laurence Fishburne]"]
title = ["The Matrix"]

actors = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(actor, title)),
                      columns = ["actor", "title"])
```

The output that I am looking for is below,

```
actor = ["Emil Eifrem", "Hugo Weaving", "Laurence Fishburne"]
title = ["The Matrix"] * 3

actors = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(actor, title)),
                      columns = ["actor", "title"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value in `actor` column is a string. You may use below to convert to a list first and then use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html).

```
actors.actor = actors.actor.str.strip('[]').str.split(',')
actors = actors.explode('actor', ignore_index=True)
```

print(actors):

```
                 actor       title
0          Emil Eifrem  The Matrix
1         Hugo Weaving  The Matrix
2   Laurence Fishburne  The Matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Generic solution even if the actor length changes

Try `eval` as mentioned below to convert the string list to actual list

```py
actor = ["[Emil Eifrem,Hugo Weaving,Laurence Fishburne]"]
actor = actor[0].strip('[]').split(',')
title = ["The Matrix"] * len(actor)

actors = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(actor, title)),
                      columns = ["actor", "title"])
# Output

      actor               title
0   Emil Eifrem         The Matrix
1   Hugo Weaving        The Matrix
2   Laurence Fishburne  The Matrix
```